# How to satisfy lifetime bounds in tokio async tasks with generics

Tags: asynchronous, generics, rust, task, lifetime

I am trying to run an async task using tokio::spawn that holds a Vec. My understanding from the compile error message is that I haven't satisfied the lifetime bounds, but I'm not sure what the correct way to achieve that is.

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc as tokiompsc;

pub fn _history<T: Clone + Send + Sync>() {
    let (data_tx, mut data_rx) = tokiompsc::channel::<T>(10);
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut destinations: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
        data_rx.recv();
    });
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src\history_generic.rs:18:5
   |
18 | /     tokio::spawn(async move {
19 | |         let mut destinations: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
20 | |         data_rx.recv();
21 | |     });
   | |______^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
16 | pub fn _history<T: Clone + Send + Sync + 'static>() {
   |                                        +++++++++
```

I have consulted the learn rust tutorial and do not understand how to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `'static` bound as mentioned in the error message? Or is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Thanks, no I only avoided it because the 'Learn Rust' warns against using it if it isn't really necessary and I didn't have the understanding. I've read the documentation provided in your answer and have a better understanding now. Using the 'static bound does seem to have addressed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consult the documentation for [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html), it requires a bound of `'static` on the future that it takes as an argument (in this case, your `async move` closure). I believe that this means that `T` needs to have the same bound since a `Vec<T>` is captured as part of the closure, and is part of the state of the `Future`. As the error message suggests, one way to avoid this would be to add  `+ 'static` to the bounds on `T`.

`'static` indicates that the type is not bound by any other lifetime shorter than the lifetime of the program - basically, if you have a `T` then that `T` does not contain a reference to any other data that might disappear while the program is running. In general, types that do not satisfy a `'static` bound cannot easily be moved between separate async tasks because that would restrict the lifetimes of those tasks.

More details on a `'static` lifetime bound: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound. As this mentions, most 'normal' owned types satisfy this bound.

Comment: _"In general, it's hard to do async programming with types that do not satisfy a `'static` bound."_ I'm not so sure this is true. You usually only have this constraint at the boundaries of tasks, and new tasks should be rather rare.

Comment: Good point, I meant if the lifetime is from something outside of the task. I'll try to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks, yes this looks like it has worked, and reading the link has helped me understand the static life time better. I did misunderstand the difference between the different ways static can be used. I did vote for the answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: The article [lifetime misconception](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) describes that `T` could be either a reference or a owned type, if it is a owned type, then `T` bound with `static` lifetime can be dropped even before the program exits, that said , I haven't figured out how Rust (or Tokio) internally handles the lifetimes from different captured values or type parameters.